# How to find distance to kth-nearest neighbor for all the points in the data set

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, distance, knn

Let's we have a matrix X of shape `(10000, 1500)`.
Let we take `k = 9`.
We want to find distance from each of the point in X to the 9th nearest point in X.

Is there any function or Sklearn library exist for this task.

```
def k_nearest_distances(X, k){
return d
}
```

d should be the array of length 10000. Where each value at index `i` represents distance to k-nearest point form `X[i]`.

Comment: I'm not aware of any but you can always calculate it by yourself. Take the distance metric you want and use its formula to calculate your desired value.

Comment: Does sklearn's nearest neightbors not do what you want? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#finding-the-nearest-neighbors ?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I find solution using sklearn library nearest neighbors using below code

```
k = 9
# importing NearestNeighbors class 
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
# initialize model
neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=k, n_jobs=-1)
# train for getting nearest neighbour
neigh.fit(X)
dist, ind = neigh.kneighbors(X)
# We have no use of indices here
# dist is a 2 dimensional array of shape (10000, 9) in which each row is list of length 9. This row contain distances to all 9 nearest points. But we need distance to only 9th nearest point. So
distances = [dist[i][k - 1] for i in range(len(dist))]
```